# Emacs OSX 10.13 configuration issue

Tags: emacs, org-mode, evil-mode

Recently I pass to Emacs org because is really convenient to me to write note there.
So I installed all packages I needed (principally ORG and EVIL) but I didn't understand how to setup everything.

I installed emacs from brew without using cask, I linked it, and I'm sure that I'm using the version that I installed (26.1).

So in my ~/ folder I have a .emacs file in which I set up evil mode, and I have a /.emacs.d/ in which I have a lot of file. The problem is: whatever I wrote in a ~/.emacs.d/init.el seems doesn't effect emacs.

So I said "whatever, I'm going on github and I installed some complete configurations and then I customized them myself". I tried to install these two configurations.

- https://github.com/hrs/dotfiles
- https://github.com/larstvei/dot-emacs?files=1

But for some reason, after doing exactly what they say on README.org
nothing happens.

In particular the second link, after install and open emacs said I need to have ~/.cask/.cask.el but I don't have it.

Advice?

Comment: "whatever i wrote in a ~/.emacs.d/init.el seems doesn't effect emacs." --

Try commenting out the entire file, and see if emacs still loads normally. If so, it seems like emacs is using a different configuration file. If it doesn't load anymore, than it might just be that certain parts of the configuration are not being loaded (maybe because of a typo, bug, etc.). You can also try using the `-debug-init` flag when you open emacs. That might give you some useful information if there is an error in your config file.

Comment: Opened with changing "init.el" to "init.el_back", the program run normally. I move the init.el to Desktop, same thing. So i try to run `emacs --debug-init` still without init.el and nothing happend. So i assume you are right, i try to search were i need the configuration file is.

Comment: It should be in one of the locations described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html

Comment: Thank you. I find the file /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/subdirs.el in which was present:  

`(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)` 
 
   ` (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))`

i add:
   
`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")`  
emacs warning me that was dangerous, so i change to:  
`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")` then i add to the file the init.el, but it remain uncompiled even if whe i tipe "C-h v load-path RET" the path is present in the output. I wrong to load init file?

Comment: You shouldn't have to load your init file, no. If it is in the correct location it should load automatically unless something else is overwritting it/taking priority over it. It is hard to say without seeing your whole setup, sorry!